# springboot+spring security+jetty stackoverflow happened when I upload large file

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jetty

I use springboot + spring security + jetty, when I upload files about 50MB using method below. This method is not called at all. But when the file size down to 2MB, it worked well!

```
@PostMapping(value = "/videos/upload", consumes=MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public BaseResponse<String> uploadVideo(MultipartFile files,
                                                    String id) {
```

[postman details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOWtG.png)
Then stackoverflow happened like below:

```
2019-10-17 22:01:08.110  WARN org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel    [567][qtp1501846707-61][][][] /videos/upload org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 400: Unable to parse form content
2019-10-17 22:01:08.126  WARN o.e.j.util.MultiPartInputStreamParser   [618][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Badly formatted multipart request
2019-10-17 22:01:08.669  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.680  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.689  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.697  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.705  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.713  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.722  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.731  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.739  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.748  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.756  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.765  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.774  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.783  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.792  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.802  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.811  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.821  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.830  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.840  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.849  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.859  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.869  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.879  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.892  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.912  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.929  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.942  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.956  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.970  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.981  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:08.994  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.005  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.015  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.027  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.037  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.048  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.189  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.200  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.212  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.223  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.235  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.246  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.257  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.268  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.280  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.295  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.306  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.318  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.330  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.342  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.357  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.370  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.382  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.394  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.406  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.420  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.445  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.460  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.526  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.543  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.556  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.568  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.580  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.593  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.607  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.619  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.632  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.650  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.663  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.676  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.690  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.703  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.717  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.730  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.748  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.761  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.774  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.786  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.801  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.813  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.826  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.841  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.857  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.870  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.883  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.896  WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound            [221][qtp1501846707-61][][][] Request method 'POST' not supported
2019-10-17 22:01:09.914  WARN o.e.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler   [126][qtp1501846707-61][][][] EXCEPTION 
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:990)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1317)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.error(Dispatcher.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler.doError(ErrorHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler.handle(ErrorHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedErrorHandler.handle(JettyEmbeddedErrorHandler.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:655)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:590)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:436)
    at .....
```

I don't know how to fix this bug, did anyone met this bug before?
  Spring Boot could be a good tool but in this time , it is so hard for me.

Comment: By default, all requests are assumed to be of HTTP GET type. Add  method = RequestMethod.POST to your @RequestMapping. Default max file size for upload is 1 MB, use property 'spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=50' to configure it as per your need.
But in case of max file size reached it will throw FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException not StackOverflow error.

Comment: I used @PostMapping yestoday ， my controller is restful, it didn't work. And the param spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size does not exist in my springboot (v1.5).